# How did birds survive the KT impact?

Tags: ornithology, palaeontology

As I understand it, the ejecta resulting from the [K-T impact](http://www.livescience.com/26933-chicxulub-cosmic-impact-dinosaurs.html) (also known as the end-Cretaceous or Cretaceous-Tertiary extinction event) re-entered the atmosphere all over the world; the heat from friction with the atmosphere raised the air temperature to a few hundred degrees C. All organisms all around the World were incinerated, except those that could bury underground or move into water.Now birds don't bury underground, nor do they   bury their eggs. So, how come birds didn't go extinct?

To clarify, I'm not considering the longer term cooling effect (which was in turn followed by a longer term warming effect due the CO2 dumped in the atmosphere). What happened just after the impact was that a sizable fraction of the entire volume involved on the collision would be on ballistic trajectories. Most of these would fall back to Earth, while a small fraction would escape Earth's gravity. Now, these ejecta actually contain a significant fraction of the total energy of the impact and almost all of that in then dissipated as heat when they re-enter the atmosphere. This leads to shock heating of the atmosphere to at least a few hundred degrees celcius, but [much higher temperatures are also possible](http://www.livescience.com/28582-asteroid-extinction-firestorm.html), see also [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgrg.20018/full).

Comment: what is the KT impact? a meteorite?

Comment: Are you sure about this: "raised the air temperature to a few hundred degrees C"? I'm not too into paleontology, but I admit I never heard that before. Could you please add a link to support that?

Comment: Unfortunately the premise underpinning this question is false. The [Cretaceous–Paleogene extinction event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event) did not raise temperatures (other than shortly and locally at the impact site) but rather _lowered_ temperatures and light levels through additional particulate matter in the air. Birds survived due to being small (like mammals of the time) and thus requiring less food. Birds could also travel to where food was, as applicable.

Comment: +1 @LateralFractal I heard from non-scientific resource too, that the survival was dependent on the weight.

Comment: @inf3rno A faster reproduction rate would have also allowed bird species to adapt faster. Whilst non-avian dinosaurs as egg layers offloaded some of their reproductive burden, each large dinosaur still had to grow (slowly) to maturation for their next generation of reproduction.

Comment: [My answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23439/how-did-aquatic-dinosaurs-go-extinct/23444#23444) to a related question about aquatic dinosaurs may help, I at least point to a [Radio Lab episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYoqtBEzuiQ) where they discuss the KT impact with geologists. Basically, anything that was on the surface of the Earth got cooked, but anything under a few inches of soil would be ok. This favored small mammals, birds, and reptiles that nested underground. While modern birds don't typically bury eggs, ancient birds may have, to hide them from predators.

Comment: @LateralFractal I think you're confusing short and long term effects on temperature. While the dust kicked up by the impact would have blocked sunlight and cooled the Earth, that took much longer than the initial firestorm immediately after the impact. Further complicating the issue would be the fires themselves, which would have released smoke that blocked additional sunlight, but also released CO2, which would have caused a longer term greenhouse effect.

Comment: @user137 I'm afraid you are going to need to provide a source for the claim that an asteroid impact globally roasted the fauna.

Comment: I've added a source in the question.

Comment: @CountIblis I can't find the originating peer-review journal article for the claim described on livescience.com. My initial scepticism is driven by 1) Air isn't a good conducter of heat and 2) Oxygen rich wild fires would have been common on that basis anyway.

Comment: @LateralFractal While Radio Lab is not a peer reviewed scientific article, they do name all the geologists they interviewed. A quick search on their names gives more information about [Kirk Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirk_Johnson_%28scientist%29), [Peter Schultz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_H._Schultz), [Jay Melosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Jay_Melosh), and [Douglas Robertson](http://www.colorado.edu/news/releases/2013/03/27/cu-study-provides-new-evidence-ancient-asteroid-caused-global-firestorm) who made the claim about temperatures.

Comment: Looking at some of the abstracts to the newer journal articles on the subject, there may be some question as the impact in the Gulf of Mexico may predate the KT boundary by a few hundred thousand years. Though if you base the extinction on the asteroid strike, then as described on the NASA JPL http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/sl9/back3.html The heat and fires would have been local, and the cooling global. The asteroid could have caused immense tidal waves.

Comment: The premise 'birds do not bury themselves underground, nor do they bury their eggs' is also false. Burrow-nesting is not uncommon among modern birds, and incubating burrow-nesting birds will often spend extended periods (multiple days, sometimes weeks) attending the nest. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge-tailed_shearwater

Comment: Detailed answer given in [this article](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(18)30534-7)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/01/090127165505.htm) hypothesizes that the surviving avians had large and quite complex brains, giving them an advantage in finding food in the aftermath.